# How to set sysroot for GDB

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, remote-debugging

**Scenario**

Dev machine running Ubuntu 20.04 and QtCreator. Qt libs are installed to `/home/mark/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib`.

Target machine running Ubuntu 20.04. Qt libs are installed to `/home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib`.

**Issue**

When debugging a remote application from QtCreator I get:

> Could not load shared library symbols for 8 libraries, e.g. /home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt6Gui.so.6.
>
> Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
>
> Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

**Setup**

In Tools > Options > Debugger > GDB > Additional Startup Commands I wrote:

```
set sysroot /home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/
set solib-search-path /home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/
```

**Questions**

1. I read somewhere that to speed up the debugging I need to set sysroot to the *local* libraries (i.e. `/home/mark/...` instead of `/home/user/...`). Which is the correct path?
2. Is it correct to set sysroot to the parent directory of the `lib` folder that contains the Qt libraries?
3. where should I run the `info sharedlibrary` command?

Answer (score 3):

> Which is the correct path?

The one where libraries can be found during debugging, i.e. the path on the development machine.

> Is it correct to set sysroot

The `sysroot` should be used when you have a *complete* set of target libraries (including *all* system ones).

That is, if you had the complete mirror of target libraries under e.g. `/home/mark/target/`, then you would use `set sysroot /home/mark/target`.

Since you don't have such a directory, you should not use `sysroot` *at all*.

Instead, you should tell GDB that it can find libraries in `/home/mark/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib` with `set solib-search-path /home/mark/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib`.

> where should I run the info sharedlibrary command?

At the `(gdb)` prompt.